# How to automatically import a SASS partials to two different main non-partial SASS files

Tags: css, architecture, sass

I have a Gulp-based SASS compilation in place. Here's my structure:

```
├── _bootstrap-custom.scss
├── _variables.scss
├── base
│   ├── _button.scss
│   ├── _fonticon.scss
│   ├── _form.scss
│   ├── _grid.scss
│   ├── _helpers.scss
│   ├── _layout.scss
│   ├── _misc.scss
│   ├── _panels.scss
│   ├── _responsive_mixin.scss
│   ├── _tabs.scss
│   └── _typography.scss
├── components
│   ├── _footer.scss
│   └── _header.scss
├── frontpage.scss
├── main.scss
└── mixins
    ├── _buttons.scss
    └── _mixins.scss
```

Here is `main.scss`

```
@import "variables.scss";

@import "bootstrap-custom";
@import "mixins/mixins";

@import "base/responsive_mixin";
@import "base/button";
@import "base/panels";
@import "base/helpers";
@import "base/form";
@import "base/layout";
@import "base/fonticon";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/misc";
@import "base/tabs";

@import "components/footer";
@import "components/header";
```

And here is `frontpage.scss`

```
@import "variables.scss";
// import other page-specific partials..
```

Here is my gulpfile SASS part:

```
var config = {
    sass: {
        src: './data/rocket/themes/rocket/sass',
        dest: './data/rocket/themes/rocket/css'
    },
    css: {
        dest: 'css/'
    },
    bootstrap: {
        src: './node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets'
    }
};

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    let files = `${config.sass.src}/**/*.scss`;
    let dest = `${config.sass.dest}`;

    console.log('=== Compiling SASS ===');

    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded',
            precision: 10,
            errLogToConsole: true,
            includePaths: config.bootstrap.src
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));

});
```

*Question* : Is there any way to automatically include `_variables.scss` in all non-partial SASS files so I don't have to manually add it?

(main/frontpage are page-specific files so they're loaded separately)

Comment: may be include all those common sass files in a single file and include it once in those pages. At least including once in each page specific main sass file is definitely necessary I think.

Comment: This might be helpful for you. [Link](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/425/automatic-import-of-lesssass-files-with-gulp)

Comment: Thanks, I had a look. I'll include manually for now hoping there's a silver bullet that solves the issue (via gulp) (the include anything plugin seems a bit extreme)